Mean value for specific latitude and longitude
I have the following problem:
I'm researching some pollutants in the State of São Paulo, Brazil.
I read the xarray data (.nc) and transformed it into DataFrame.
For each coordinate (longitude, latitude) I have data for five years (from 01-01-2015 until 31-12-2019)
Update
As an example:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['01-01-2015 00:00:00', '01-01-2015 03:00:00', '02-01-2015 00:00:00', '02-01-2015 03:00:00', '10-01-2015 00:00:00'], 
'latitude': [-55.0, -55.0, -52.0, -52.0, -43.0],
'longitude': [-18.5, -18.5, -21.5, -21.5, -26.0],
'PM': [10, 20, 20, 30, 35]})

For the coordinate, (-55, -18.5), PM mean value has to be 15 (10+20/2).
For the coordinate, (-52, -21.5), PM mean value has to be 25 (20+30/2).
For the coordinate, (-43, -26), PM mean value has to be 55 (35/1).
I want to obtain just the mean values for PM column, and to do that, I have to use the date and maintain the coordinates as they are.
How can I group the dates to use the mean method, and maintain the coordinates intact?

Give us a [mcve] not images.  Provide a dataframe as text with a couple days of data for a couple of lat/long.  See How to make good reproducible pandas examples

I'm sorry for these images. I thought that it could help to understand my problem. Next time, I'll make a good example

In general, give code and data as text.  Read the pandas link for ways to limit a dump your existing dataframe that can be pasted into a question so we don't have to manually generate data to give an example.

SOLUTION 1
You may simply convert your time to datetime and extract the corresponding date. You may then calculate the mean by grouping by date:
d_cams['date']=pd.to_datetime(d_cams['time']).dt.date 
d_cams.groupby('date').mean()

SOLUTION 2
Alternatively, you may call...
d_cams.resample('D').mean()

...without specifying "longitude" or "latitude", in order to compute the mean over all columns.
EXAMPLE
Considering the following example dataframe...
d_cams = pd.DataFrame()
d_cams['latitude'] = [-18.5, -26, -26]
d_cams['longitude'] = [-55, -43, -43]
d_cams['pm'] = [1.49e-08, 1.16e-08, 1.54e-08]
d_cams['time'] = ['2015-01-01 00:00:00','2015-01-01 00:30:00','2015-01-02 00:00:00']

...both solutions yield the same output:
            latitude    longitude   pm
date            
2015-01-01  -22.25          -49     1.325000e-08
2015-01-02  -26.00          -43     1.540000e-08

